# Restrict facets set in apache solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, faceted-search, facet

I use apache solr for my search engine. I have a schema with a field called "typology". I'd like to search inside all typologies but i need to calculate facets of many fields for only one typology. Is it possible?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have an example? You want to limit the facet generation to documents with a special value in one field (in practice making a `fq` valid for just the facets, and not for the actual query)?

Answer (score 0):

Your base query for facets does not have to be the same as your search query. [facet.query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-Thefacet.queryParameter) parameter allows you to have a different search for that.

Comment: If i add facet.query parameter, solr doens't filter all facets count but it only adds a new count field based on the parameter. I want to restrict the range of facets. Is it possible? like and fq parameter, but only on facet count.

Comment: Ah, it looks like I misread the question. You might be able to use Pivot Faceting for it (facet on taxonomy first, then other fields), but it would be a bit slower. There is also Tagging, but that's for a reverse problem of ignoring some of the filters. Both of these are described at the same link as above.